# Finding the equation of a hyperbola given the foci and a tangent line

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, conic-sections

How would one calculate the equation of a hyperbola given the foci and a tangent line?

So far I've only figured out that I can find the $c$ through the foci. I would be really thankful if someone could help.

Comment: Reflect $F_1$ about the tangent to $F_1'$. The intersection between line $F_2F_1'$ and the tangent is the tangency point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

As the image above clearly shows, it is a property of hyperbola that the tangent line at any point $T$ on the hyperbola, makes equal angles with the line segments $TF_1$ and $TF_2$.  This as remarked by @intelligentipauca above, can be used to find the tangency point $T$ given the tangent line and the two foci $F_1$ and $F_2$.  Reflecting the right focus $F_2$ about the line results in $F_2'$ which due to the tangent line being the angle bisector of $\angle F_1 T F_2$ will lie on $T F_1$.  Thus we can find the tangent point $T$ by intersecting the line $F_1 F_2'$ and the tangent line.

Now that we have $T$, a point on the hyperbola, whose equation is

$ \dfrac{x^2}{a^2} - \dfrac{y^2}{b^2 } = 1 $

We know the foci at $F_1 = (-c, 0) $ and $F_2 = (c, 0)$, so we know $ c^2 = a^2 + b^2 $

Further, substituting the coordinates of $T= (T_x, T_y) $ we get

$ \dfrac{T_x^2}{a^2} - \dfrac{T_y^2}{b^2 } = 1 $

Solving the above two equations for $a^2 $ and $b^2$ gives the hyperbola equation.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.